# How to put for loop inside function for "getElementById"?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to put for loop for below function i want loop in "textInput" field so i use same function for different Id's linke textInput1, textInput2,.....

```
function onButtonClick(){
  document.getElementById('textInput').className="show";
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you could do the task by using [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation) instead of a bunch of `id`s. If you can show some more context (the relevant markup), we could suggest a suitable code for the delegation.

Comment: Use a class instead of multiple IDs? That's what classes are for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass id in onclick event and use it like below

```js
function onButtonClick(id){
  document.getElementById('textInput'+id).className="show";
}
```

```css
.show{
display:block
}
.hide{
display:none
}
```

```html
<input type='button' value='Add' onclick='onButtonClick(1)'>

<div class='show'>show</div>
```

Or you can also use following but it will run repeatedly when click on button

```
  function onButtonClick(){
for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
document.getElementById('textInput'+i).className="show";
}
      
    }
```